# compare values and open the highlighted PivotDetails

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data that I want to automate at the stage of PivotTable. Given the following data in PivotTable:

[image]

I would like to loop through Range ("A6:A" & secondlastcell) and do the following tasks:

1. If cell.Value in the Range A is "Mel" and "Ari", then compare their values in Column G, highlight the higher value among them in Range G in yellow.
2. ElseIf both Mel and Ari's sum of amount are the same then highlight Ari's value in Range G in yellow.

1 to 2 to be applied the same for "Jason" and "Jack".

3. After that, filter the highlighted values and ShowDetails in new worksheet.

The output would be 1 sheet showing the Data Details of Mel/Ari whereas another sheet showing the Data Details of Jason/Jack.

The following is the macro I attempted to make but stuck:

```
Sub test()

    Dim CheckRange As Range, CheckRange2 As Range
    Dim LastCell As Long, SecondLastCell As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
    
        LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        SecondLastCell = LastCell - 1
        
        Set CheckRange = .Range("A6:A" & SecondLastCell)
        Set CheckRange2 = .Range("G6:G" & SecondLastCell)
        
    End With
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In CheckRange
    
        Dim MelvsAri As Range
        If Cell.Value2 = "Mel" Or Cell.Value2 = "Ari" Then
            
                'Store a reference to the corresping cell with data
                Dim Data As Range
                Set Data = Intersect(Cell.EntireRow, CheckRange2)
                
                If MelvsAri Is Nothing Then
                    Set MelvsAri = Data
                Else
                    If MelvsAri.Value2 < Data.Value2 Then
                        Set MelvsAri = Data
                    ElseIf MelvsAri.Value2 = Data.Value2 Then
                        'If both have the same value, then both will be highlighted
                        Set MelvsAri = Union(MelvsAri, Data)
                    End If
                End If

        Dim JasonvsJack As Range
        ElseIf Cell.Value2 = "Jason" Or Cell.Value2 = "Jack" Then
              
                If JasonvsJack Is Nothing Then
                    Set JasonvsJack = Data
                Else
                    If JasonvsJack.Value2 < Data.Value2 Then
                        Set JasonvsJack = Data
                    ElseIf JasonvsJack.Value2 = Data.Value2 Then
                        'If both have the same value, then both will be highlighted
                        Set JasonvsJack = Union(JasonvsJack, Data)
                    End If
                End If
  
        End If
                
    Next Cell
    
    'After the loop has finished, we know that the maximum value(s) is referenced by MelvsAri / JasonvsJack, so we can highlight them.
    MelvsAri.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    JasonvsJack.Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

Seek your help to guide me on this macro please.

**P/S: Removed my previous edits as it has been resolved.

Comment: Are you having trouble with getting the values from `checkrange2`, once you have the cell that contains one of the values that you want, is that it?

Comment: Your question as it stands is asking about multiple things and it might be better to separate them. I've isolated a part of your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77592526/5958842), to make it more targeted and hopefully easier to follow and find by others.

Comment: @DecimalTurn Thanks for simplifying my question. Taking the data as example, I want the macro to loop through Column A, whenever there are "Mel" and "Ari" in Range A, I need the macro to pick the higher value among them and have the higher value highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address part 1 and 2 of your question, you could try this:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim CheckRange As Range, CheckRange2 As Range
    
    
    Dim LastCell As Long, SecondLastCell As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
    
        LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        SecondLastCell = LastCell - 1
        
        Set CheckRange = .Range("A6:A" & SecondLastCell)
        Set CheckRange2 = .Range("G6:G" & SecondLastCell)
        
    End With
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In CheckRange
    
        Dim MelvsAri As Range
        If Cell.Value2 = "Mel" Or Cell.Value2 = "Ari" Then
            
                'Store a reference to the corresping cell with data
                Dim Data As Range
                Set Data = Intersect(Cell.EntireRow, CheckRange2)
                
                If MelvsAri Is Nothing Then
                    Set MelvsAri = Data
                Else
                    If MelvsAri.Value2 < Data.Value2 Then
                        Set MelvsAri = Data
                    ElseIf MelvsAri.Value2 = Data.Value2 Then
                        'If both have the same value, then both will be highlighted
                        Set MelvsAri = Union(MelvsAri, Data)
                    End If
                End If
                
        End If
                
    Next Cell
    
    'After the loop has finished, we know that the maximum value(s) is/are referenced by MelvsAri, so we can highlight it/them.
    MelvsAri.Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

**Some explanations**

You'll see that `Data` in this case is the range that contains the value in column G. We then use the variable MelvsAri to contain the range with the biggest value we have found so far while looping over the range with the names.

The first time around, `MelvsAri` is not initialized, so `Is nothing` will return true. In that case we know that whatever the value inside the data range, we know that it's the biggest we've found so far because `MelvsAri` is "empty". This means that we can assing `MelvsAri` to the range where `data` is pointing.

Then we only change the value for `MelvsAri` if a subsequent data range is presented with a bigger value.

---

Note that I haven't done it of the names "Jason" and "Jack", but you can certainly replicate the approach for "Mel" and "Ari". If at some point you have lot of pairs, another approach might be better to avoid repeating code, but for just 2 pairs, I'd say you can copy the existing code and just change the names.

---

EDIT:

In the case where they are equal, if you want the cell corresponding to a specific name to always be the one highlighted, you can use somehting like this instead:

```vb
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In CheckRange
    
        Dim MelvsAri As Range
        If Cell.Value2 = "Mel" Or Cell.Value2 = "Ari" Then
            
                'Store a reference to the corresping cell with data
                Dim Data As Range
                Set Data = Intersect(Cell.EntireRow, CheckRange2)
                
                If MelvsAri Is Nothing Then
                    Set MelvsAri = Data
                Else
                    If MelvsAri.Value2 < Data.Value2 Then
                        Set MelvsAri = Data
                    ElseIf MelvsAri.Value2 = Data.Value2 And Cell.Value2 = "Ari" Then
                        Set MelvsAri = Data
                    End If
                End If
                
        End If
                
    Next Cell
    
    'After the loop has finished, we know that the maximum value is referenced by MelvsAri, so we can highlight it.
    MelvsAri.Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Notice that if they are equal, we now check the name and replace the value already in MelvsAri only if the new cell corresponds to "Ari".

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked! I do have a follow-up question.. `If MelvsAri Is Nothing Then Set MelvsAri = Data Else If MelvsAri.Value2 < Data.Value2 Then Set MelvsAri = Data` Can you provide some explanation on how this part of code works? I'm confused how MelvsAri and Data value come into play

Comment: I tried it with "Jason" and "Jack" it worked as well - using for loop. Question: Is there a way to highlight only one value if both values are the same? For example, "Mel" and "Ari" have the same values in Column G, but I only wanted to highlight Ari's.

Comment: @JeffCh I've added some explanation to the answer. Let me know if that clears things up! Regarding highlighting only one value when they are equal, what is the rule to decide which value to highlight? Is it always Ari or does that depend on the order of the rows?

Comment: Thanks once again, I understood the code better now. The rule to decide which value to highlight when the values are equal is that of the value in Range A is always Ari.

Comment: @JeffCh I've edited the condition to take care of the equality scenario.

Comment: Cheers! The codes work well now though I'm having issues with the pivotcache, will look for solution on my end. Allow me to raise the final question: the macro now covers Mel, Ari Jack and Jason. I'm looking at a line of code for `else any other values in Range A with value more than (say) 500K in Range G will be highlighted`. Could you give a suggestion on how I can do that?

Comment: @JeffCh I'm not sure if I understand you question correctly. At this point, I'd be willing to help, but in a seperate question.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I've marked it as the answer. I just posted my question in another thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77604389/cont-follow-up-question-on-selecting-value-based-on-scenario-3