# How to get the corresponding cell from another column while looping over a range

Tags: excel, vba

This question is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77589391/excel-vba-to-compare-values-and-open-the-highlighted-pivotdetails), but I've tried to simplify it in order to make it easier for VBA beginners to follow by illustrating a single concept.

Let's say that I have the following data :

[image]

[<sup>Data</sup>](https://itty.bitty.site/#/data:text/html;charset=utf-8;bxze64,XQAAAAT//////////wAeHQgmOm3if1cj0EddAG11avRu8JLrozXRddsoRVlEd631IerpCKQfigEc8ODne+xkQhGTSQr1H6NaQ6bvJ7R3ItxTRquiPaLWQk/BrTq/m2suSOnJCAsE+uAXGaF+oBL2Y1aODVPptMfAYKlwvG8DB6lqf9NRRLMsuH2/mmeMx1ugIFZRPtA3AuWzHD6LpYARPESbuy1sTMpJ9CzHTWQE428nsxJ07sU9ajryChaRfArsWYgh+uax093Y79Rju1KGmpcq9Go5mTHfFGzRKw9AfK40XKEnWTRkvMaeQ8kZmRkAOgONf2Ir9Fpm+jpJEMmsAgIlNm5bYiQae4aBeLhFm+joMCLvIL07zLJndoHCVPzeBp5sD2pgBnl+Uy+5IM2hrgNQKI5pCWIc+P7p7a/Cf89o5LDBQviPuErZBjZ+/yhGWR7DOL9Cx1PCvO32TMDfVGpdYsvJ7Eeh/4CBZwA=)

Now, I need to highlight cells in columns D if the `Id` number is smaller than 200.

This means that I'm expecting the following:

[image]

Now, here is the initial code:

```vb
    Dim LoopingRange As Range
    Dim CheckRange As Range
    
    Dim LastCellRow As Long, SecondToLastCellRow As Long
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
        LastCellRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        SecondToLastCellRow = LastCellRow - 1
        
        Set LoopingRange = .Range("A2:A" & SecondToLastCellRow)
        Set CheckRange = .Range("D2:D" & SecondToLastCellRow)
        
    End With
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In LoopingRange
    
        If Cell.Value2 < 200 Then
            
            'Highlight the corresponding cell in column D
                    
        End If
                
    Next Cell
```

It allows to loop over the cells in column A, but when the condition is satisfied, it needs a way to tell VBA to get the corresponding cell in the same column and highlight it. What is the simplest what to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple approaches that can work for this. Here's a few:

1. Using `Intersect()`
2. Using `Cells()`
3. Using a `Range()`

### 1. Using Intersect()

```vb
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In LoopingRange
    
        If Cell.Value2 < 200 Then
            
            'Highlight the corresponding cell in column D
            Intersect(Cell.EntireRow, CheckRange).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    
        End If
                
    Next Cell
```

The advantage of using Intersect is that it makes it clear that you are taking the same row and you could even replace `CheckRange` with `Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("D")` and it would also work.

### 2. Using Cells()

```vb
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For Each Cell In LoopingRange
    
        i = i + 1
    
        If Cell.Value2 < 200 Then
            
            'Highlight the corresponding cell in column D
            CheckRange.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    
        End If
                
    Next Cell
```

This takes advantage of the fact that calling the `Cells` method on a range makes everything relative to the top left cell of that range = Cells(1,1). Note that this approach needs you to include a counter variable (`i` in this case).

### 3. Using Range()

```vb
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In LoopingRange
    
        If Cell.Value2 < 200 Then
            
            'Highlight the corresponding cell in column D
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Cell.Row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    
        End If
                
    Next Cell
```

This approach takes advantage of the fact that both cells are on the same row to create an address as a string and pass it to the fully qualified `Range()` method.
(Note that calling the Range method without attaching it on the left to a sheet object means that you are calling the method on the ActiveSheet).

Answer (score 1):

Use Offset() property of Range object by setting the columnOffset parameter to 3 (i.e. three columns to the right of the referenced range)

```
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In LoopingRange

    If Cell.Value2 < 200 Then
        
        'Highlight the corresponding cell in column D
        Cell.Offset(0, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    End If
            
Next
```

Or you could use:

```
        Cell.Offset(0, CheckRange.Column - cell.Column).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

So that the column offset is dynamic

And, since that column offset is also the same throughout the loop, you could set it outside the loop:

```
Dim colOffset As Long
colOffset = CheckRange.Column - LoopingRange.Column
```

and use it inside the loop

```
        Cell.Offset(0, colOffset).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Comment: @DecimalTurn, just edited my answer and added some stuff as to how to avoid the potential “off by one” error

Comment: Awesome! I would upvote again if I could. I'll delete my comment(s) now that it has been addressed.

Answer (score 1):

### Highlight Column

[image]

```vb
Sub HighlightColumn()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Highlight Column"
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CRITERIA_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const CRITERIA_LESS_THAN As Double = 200
    Const HIGHLIGHT_COLUMN As String = "D"
    Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR As Long = vbYellow
    Const HAS_TOTALS_ROW As Boolean = True

    ' Reference the workbook and worksheet.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Reference the Criteria range.
    
    Dim crg As Range
    
    With ws.Range(CRITERIA_FIRST_CELL)
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column) _
            .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1 + HAS_TOTALS_ROW ' False = 0, True = -1
        If rCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "No data found!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set crg = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
    
    ' Combine the matching cells of the Criteria range into a range union.
    
    Dim curg As Range, cell As Range, CellValue As Variant
    
    For Each cell In crg.Cells
        CellValue = cell.Value
        If VarType(CellValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            If CellValue < CRITERIA_LESS_THAN Then
                If curg Is Nothing Then
                    Set curg = cell
                Else
                    Set curg = Union(curg, cell)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Clear existing highlights (in the Highlight range).
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = crg.EntireRow.Columns(HIGHLIGHT_COLUMN)
    hrg.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    
    ' Highlight in one go.
    
    If curg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No matching criteria found!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    curg.Offset(, hrg.Column - crg.Column).Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Column values highlighted.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

Comment: Great stuff! Could you please add an explaination on how `EntireRow.Columns` actually returns a single cell instead of a column? I'm trying to make sure the answers to this post are as approchable for beginers as possible.

Comment: If you do `Set rg = Range("A2:A11")` or `Set rg = Range("F2:F11")`... then `rg.EntireRow` references `A2:XFD11` while `rg.EntireRow.Columns("D")` or `rg.EntireRow.Columns(4)` reference `D2:D11`.

Comment: Ah yes, in that case it's more than one row to start with, so we get a range and not a single cell. This would be worth mentionning in the content of the answer imo.