# (Cont.) Follow-up question on selecting value based on Scenario 3

Tags: excel, vba

This is a follow-up question from my [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77589391/compare-values-and-open-the-highlighted-pivotdetails/77592934?noredirect=1#comment136799700_77592934). After assigning rules for Mel, Ari, Jason and Jack, I would like to have another line of code: In the event of the value in Range A is anything else other than "Mel", "Ari", "Jason" and "Jack", highlight value in Range G based on the criteria shown in the below screenshot-(Scenario 3).
[image]

Code is as follows:

```
Sub test()

    Dim CheckRange As Range, CheckRange2 As Range
    Dim LastCell As Long, SecondLastCell As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
    
        LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        SecondLastCell = LastCell - 1
        
        Set CheckRange = .Range("A6:A" & SecondLastCell)
        Set CheckRange2 = .Range("G6:G" & SecondLastCell)
        
    End With
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In CheckRange
    
        Dim MelvsAri As Range
        If Cell.Value2 = "Mel" Or Cell.Value2 = "Ari" Then
            
                'Store a reference to the corresping cell with data
                Dim Data As Range
                Set Data = Intersect(Cell.EntireRow, CheckRange2)
                
                If MelvsAri Is Nothing Then
                    Set MelvsAri = Data
                Else
                    If MelvsAri.Value2 < Data.Value2 Then
                        Set MelvsAri = Data
                    ElseIf MelvsAri.Value2 = Data.Value2 And Cell.Value2 = "Ari" Then
                        'If both have the same value, highlight only Ari's
                        Set MelvsAri = Data
                    End If
                End If

        Dim JasonvsJack As Range
        ElseIf Cell.Value2 = "Jason" Or Cell.Value2 = "Jack" Then
              
                If JasonvsJack Is Nothing Then
                    Set JasonvsJack = Data
                Else
                    If JasonvsJack.Value2 < Data.Value2 Then
                        Set JasonvsJack = Data
                    ElseIf JasonvsJack.Value2 = Data.Value2 Then
                        'If both have the same value, then both will be highlighted
                        Set JasonvsJack = Union(JasonvsJack, Data)
                    End If
                End If
        **ElseIf cell.Value2 <> "Mel" Or cell.Value2 <> "Ari" Or cell.Value2 <> "Jack" Or cell.Value2 <> "Jason" Then
             'Code to capture & highlight Range G.Value that is written under Scenario 3 in screenshot**

        End If
                
    Next Cell
    
    'After the loop has finished, we know that the maximum value(s) is referenced by MelvsAri / JasonvsJack, so we can highlight them.
    MelvsAri.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    JasonvsJack.Interior.Color = vbYellow

End Sub
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any additional techniques necessary to solve this compared to your previous question (calculating maximum, conditional statements and variable manipulation). Have you tried something to perform this yet?